# How do I select every row from a table based on a string containing the name of the table?

Tags: mysql, sql, prepared-statement, dynamic-sql

In MySQL, I have a number of procedures which are more or less identical - they all perform the same (or very similar) operations, but they perform it on different tables.

I'd like to reduce these to one procedure, parameterized by table name, if possible. For example, suppose I wanted to execute a generic select:

```
SELECT * FROM TableFor("TableName")
```

Is this (or anything similar) possible in MySQL? Is it possible in any SQL dialect?

**Per Tomva's Answer**

A full example:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS example;

CREATE PROCEDURE example(IN tablename VARCHAR(1000)) BEGIN
  SET @statement = CONCAT('SELECT * FROM ', @tablename);

  PREPARE statement FROM @statement;
  EXECUTE statement;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE statement;
END;

CALL example('tablename');
```

Comment: This is possible using dynamic SQL and loops.  The syntax differs considerably among one SQL engines.

Comment: Well you could just make your query with @tablename and fill it in dynamically

Comment: This sounds like something you would use a [Stored Procedure](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-stored-procedures.html) for

Comment: nobody answer this question, give me a couple minutes to put my answer together :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with a  [*prepared statement*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html).

It will be something along the lines of

```
SET @stat = CONCAT('SELECT * FROM ', @tab'); 

PREPARE stat1 FROM @stat; 
EXECUTE stat1; 
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stat1;
```

Dynamic SQL does not work in a function, so make a Stored Procedure from this, and you will be able to provide the table parameter.

Comment: Works. Thanks Tomva. I'm going to update my question with a complete stored procedure that employs this code.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume you know what a stored procedure is (I hope you do otherwise my answer will be useless)

First create a table object in your procedure

```
declare @tablenames table(name varchar)
insert into @MonthsSale (name) values ('firsttable')
insert into @MonthsSale (name) values ('secondtable')
...
```

You can add this little line to suppress the rows affected messages:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
```

Then create a cursor for this table and a variable to save your table name

```
DECLARE @TABLENAME VARCHAR
DECLARE tables_cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT name FROM @tablenames
```

Then loop through cursor and execute your code for each table name

```
OPEN Tables_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM Tables_cursor INTO @Tablename

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
  YOUR CODE USING THE @Tablename
END
CLOSE Tables_cursor
DEALLOCATE Tables_cursor
```

Comment: These snippets do not appear to be valid MySQL code. I don't recommend using them.